# Representations of $\text{Sp}(n,1)$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, group-homomorphism, symmetric-spaces

Can anyone help me understand why there are no nontrivial homomorphisms $\text{Sp}(n,1) \to \text{GL}(d,\mathbb{R})$ if $n$ is sufficiently large relative to $d$?

By definition, $\text{Sp}(n,1)$ is the isometry group of $n$-dimensional quaternionic hyperbolic space. (By the way, does anyone know of a definition in terms of matrices or more familiar Lie groups?)

Comment: Well, it'd restrict to a homomorphism from $Sp(n)$, which is simple (modulo a discrete subgroup), which means the image would have to have the same dimension... (and also you can reason with maximal compact subgroups but that's not necessary). BTW the matrix definition of $Sp(n,1)$ would be $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ quaternionic matrices preserving the sesquilinear form of signature $(1,n)$ on $\Bbb H^n\times\Bbb H$.

Comment: What is the relation between $\text{Sp}(n,1)$ and $\text{Sp}(n)$? And just to clarify, you're saying that $n \ge d$ is sufficient?

Comment: $Sp(n)$ is subgroup of $Sp(n,1)$. And my comment did not imply $n\ge d$ is sufficient. Since the dim of $Sp(n)$ is $n(2n+1)$ and the dim of $GL_d(\Bbb R)$ is $d^2$, my comment implies $n(2n+1)>d^2$ is sufficient for there to not be an embedding. (But this bound can definitely be improved with some other observations, for example my comment about maximal compact subgroups.)

Comment: I must've had a brain fart to forget to count dimensions...But in any case I see what you're saying, thank you.