# Embedding Sp($n$,1) into GL($d,\mathbb{R}$)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

This is a follow-up question to my old post: [Representations of $\text{Sp}(n,1)$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3936684/representations-of-textspn-1-on-mathbbrd)

What is the smallest $d$ for which there exists an embedding of Sp($n$,1) into GL($d,\mathbb{R}$)?

My initial thought is that Sp($n$,1) should embed into GL($d,\mathbb{R}$) for $d = 4(n+1)$ because Sp($n$,1) is a subgroup of the $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ matrices over the quaternions, and the field of quaternions is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$ in a sense. But I'm not sure how to determine whether or not $d=4(n+1)$ is optimal.